# Get Custom Setting's field value in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customsetting, lightning-components

I have a custom setting with API Name: **Company_Setting__c**. I need to access the value stored in this custom setting in lightning component. I got a field with API Name: **Company_Phone__c**.

Below is my code:

**Apex Controller:**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Company_Setting__c getCompanySetting(){
    return Company_Setting__c.getInstance();
}
```

**Ligntning Component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="companySetting" type="Map" default="{}" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

**Lightning Component Controller:**

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var getSettingsAction = component.get("c.getCompanySetting");

    getSettingsAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (component.isValid() && response !== null && response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.companySetting", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log("Company Setting loaded.");
        } else {
            console.log("Failed to load Company Setting.");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(getSettingsAction);
}
```

However, when use a button to alert with value `alert(component.get("v.companySetting.Company_Phone__c"));` it just show as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you implemented is correct.

The problem could be 1. You are not getting `Company_Setting__c` values OR 2. API name might be wrong - case sensitive. Put logs in both places - apex and lightning - and check.

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Company_Setting__c getCompanySetting(){
    System.debug('Company_Setting__c.getInstance() => '+Company_Setting__c.getInstance());
    return Company_Setting__c.getInstance();
}
```

JS:

```
if (component.isValid() && response !== null && response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.companySetting", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log("Company Setting loaded."+JSON.stringify(component.get("v.companySetting")));
        }
```

Now test both apex logs and browser logs to verify and correct it